# Drawing a circle using google maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I m trying to draw a circle using map object obtained from an iframe as follows.

```
function modificaradio(){

var mapaZonas = geContentWindow(validateParentParentFrame('ifrmMapaZonasSeguras')).mapZone;
    geContentWindow(validateParentParentFrame('ifrmMapaZonasSeguras')).geoDragzs.setMap(null);
    var centroZonas = geContentWindow(validateParentParentFrame('ifrmMapaZonasSeguras')).newCenter;


    geContentWindow(validateParentParentFrame('ifrmMapaZonasSeguras')).geoDragzs = drawCircle(centroZonas,radio, colorContorno, anchoContorno, opacidadContorno, colorRelleno, opacidadRelleno);

    geContentWindow(validateParentParentFrame('ifrmMapaZonasSeguras')).geoDragzs.setMap(mapaZonas);
}
```

Below is the function to draw the circle

```
function drawCircle(center, radioCirculo,colorContorno,anchoContorno,opacidadContorno,colorRelleno,opacidadRelleno) {
nodes=40;
//se agrega un porcentaje al radio del circulo para su equivalencia en tamaño con mapInfo
var radioExtra = parseInt(radioCirculo * 0.10);
//el radio de la geocerca (dado en metros), se pasa a kilometros
var radioCirculoTot = (parseInt(radioCirculo) + radioExtra) / 1000;

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


var lat1 = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 0.1, center.lng());
var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, lat1) / 100;
var lng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(), center.lng() + 0.1);
var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, lng2) / 100;
//Loop
var points = [];
var step = parseInt(360 / nodes) || 10;
for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i += step) {
    var pint = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + (radioCirculoTot / latConv * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180)), center.lng() +
        (radioCirculoTot / lngConv * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)));
    points.push(pint);
}
points.push(points[0]);
geocercaRadio = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: colorContorno,
        strokeOpacity: opacidadContorno,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: colorRelleno,
        fillOpacity: opacidadRelleno
    });

return geocercaRadio;
```

}

Function used to create the map is as below.

```
function cargaMapaZonas(mapa,longitud, latitud, radio, idRadio){
        zoomRadio = validaZoomRadio(idRadio);
        var mapProp = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud),
            zoom:zoomRadio,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
             },
            streetViewControl:false};
            mapZone=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapa),mapProp);
            radioGeo = radio;

        newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud);
        centroDragzs = agregaMarcadorGeo(imgCenterGeo, 10, 10, newCenter);
        centroDragzs.setMap(mapZone);
//      geoDragzs=drawCircle(radioGeo,newCenter,mapZone);
        geoDragzs=drawCircle(newCenter,radioGeo, colorContorno, anchoContorno, opacidadContorno, colorRelleno, opacidadRelleno);
        geoDragzs.setMap(mapZone);
        //geoDragzs.bindTo('center', centroDragzs , 'position');
        geoDragzs.clickable = false;        
        google.maps.event.addListener(centroDragzs, "click", function(){
        var shape = {
                coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };            
            var bbMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    icon: 'img/visor/mm_20_red.png',
                    shadow: 'img/visor/mm_20_shadow.png',
                    shape: shape,
                    position: newCenter,
                    draggable:true,                 
                    map: map
                });
            bbMarker.setMap(mapZone);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        google.maps.event.addListener(bbMarker, "dragend", function(){
                geoDragzs.setMap(null);
                newCenter = bbMarker.getPosition();
                centroDragzs.setPosition(newCenter);
                geoDragzs=drawCircle(newCenter,radioGeo, colorContorno, anchoContorno, opacidadContorno, colorRelleno, opacidadRelleno);
                geoDragzs.setMap(mapZone);
                bbMarker.setMap(null);
                mapZone.panTo(newCenter);
                parent.document.getElementById("longitud").value = newCenter.lng();
                parent.document.getElementById("latitud").value = newCenter.lat();
                showLocationfp(newCenter);
            });
        });

}
```

Here the thing is that I m able to create the circle while calling cargaMapaZonas().But when I m calling from modificaradio() I m getting `"invalid value for  property <map> <object,object>"` error
Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

When `draw_circle` isn't defined already,  `draw_circle` is not `null`, it's `undefined` and the comparison will end in an error.
check the type instead:

```
 if (typeof draw_circle !='undefined')
  {draw_circle.setMap(null);}
```

instead, using `typeof` with undefined objects will not raise an error.

Comment: I had added var draw_circle = null; in the code and has edited the question. I was wondering is there any error in the way in which I m retrieving the map object from the iframe.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the functions that you use there.

Comment: It would be the best when you give us a link to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas :

- if `draw_circle` is defined in an outer scope, then there's probably no need to return `draw_circle` from the function.
- To determine whether the var has been set or not, you can simply test `if(draw_circle)`.
- if `center` is already a `google.maps.LatLng` object, then there's no need to construct another, identical one.
- `position` option does not exist (it won't do any harm but also nothing good).
- `rad *= 1600 / 1000` looks wrong. 1600 is (approx) the conversion from miles to metres, and 1000 is the conversion from km to metres. 1600 / 1000 would be some rather strange conversion (thousandths of a mile to metres?).

The mention of an iFrame is unclear. I can't comment on this aspect.

```
function DrawCircleGeo(rad,center,map) {
    rad *= 1600 / 1000;
    if (draw_circle) {
        draw_circle.setMap(null);
    }
    draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: center,
        radius: rad,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably, but not for about 4 hours. Maybe the good Herr Dr M has more time right now.

Comment: It appears that the call from `modificaradio()` fails because at least one of the parameters does not exist or is out of scope. The most obvious candidate is `radio`.

Comment: I m getting both the parameters and the error comes only when the circle is set on the map. :(

Comment: Then, maybe `modificaradio()` gets called before the map has been initialized. It's not possible for me to know from seeing just the code snippets above.

Comment: Actually the modificaradio() function is called from a jsp other than the jsp with the map div element.So only I was getting the map object from the iframe in the modificaradio().The weird part is that i m able to call the function getZoom on the map object retrieved but cannot set this cirlce.Hope its not any bug in V3 because I was able to do the same in V2